# Can i use 301 redirect for sitemap.xml file location

Tags: googlebot, sitemap

I want to keep the autogenerated sitemap.xml on a different server.

Will google follow 301 redirect while trying to fetch sitemap.xml?

https://example.com/sitemap.xml --301--> https://static.anotherexample.com/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Google will follow the 301 (It probably will). However, the safer choice is to add the new link of the sitemap.xml in your robot.txt like this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

You can read more about it here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en